# How to set different year range in different datepicker by id

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have some of datepickers with jQuery. I wanna set year range in all of datepickers, but the year range isn't same between them. I set like this

```
    $( "#BD" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth :true,
        changeYear : true,
        yearRange: "c-40:+c-15"
    });

    $( "#ST" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth :true,
        changeYear : true,
        yearRange: "c-40:+c+0"
    });
    $( "#ED" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth :true,
        changeYear : true,
        yearRange: "c-40:+c+0"
    });
```

The result, all of datepickers use the first year range in id=BD. What should I do?

Comment: add demo to show the current output vs the expected output

Answer (score 0):

c-40:c+40 will show the range based on each datepicker's current selection.

Remove the c and just use -40:+15 (change values per your need) as described [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange).

Comment: [SOLVED] I set all of datetime picker not in one function. I move all in one function, it works..!! Thanks for answering my question

Comment: When you select a date in one of the datepicker - it's range will change because c-40 refers to the current selected date - 40 years but when you specify just -40, it means 40 years before today. So, you may still need to change it to remove c.